# Let $g \in L^1(0,\infty)$ and consider the function $f(x)$ defined as an integral. Prove $f$ is differentiable and calculate $f'$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, derivatives, lebesgue-integral, lebesgue-measure

Let $g \in L^1(0,\infty)$ and consider the function
$$f(x) = \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy}g(y)dy$$
for $x \in (0,\infty)$. Prove that $f$ is differentiable for all $x > 0$ and compute $f'(x)$.

I had a thought to use the definition of the derivative. I think it may work out! Would that be a way to go about this one?

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-(x + h)y}g(y)dy - \int_{0}^{\infty} e^{-xy}g(y)dy}{h}$$

Then,

$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} [e^{-x - h}e^{y}g(y) - e^{-xy}g(y) ]dy}{h}$$
$$\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{\int_{0}^{\infty} [e^{-xy}g(y)(e^{-h}-1)]dy}{h}$$

From here, I'm a bit stuck. I know I am getting somewhere as $\lim_{h \to 0} \frac{e^{-h} - 1}{h} = -1$, and that wouldn't be appearing for no reason. Can I move the limit inside here? Or am I on the wrong track?

The theorems below as answers I have not covered, and do not make sense. I need a different approach.

Comment: $$\frac{f(c+h) - f(c)}{h} =  \int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(c+h)} - e^{-c}}{h}g(y)dy$$

The point is to show that the limit as $h \to 0$ can be taken inside the integral.

Comment: Wait, what's c? I have x and y. And I don't see a limit there. I know there is a limit in the derivative definition, but what are you trying to get at here? And what about that limit? I have a g(y) involved still, so how could I finish the problem? I'm not really seeing it all put together.

Comment: I used $c$ instead of $x$, and I meant $$\int_0^{\infty} \frac{e^{-(c+h)y} - e^{-cy}}{h} g(y)dy$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$f(x)=\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}g(y)\,dy$$
by the Liebniz rule:
$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^\infty e^{-xy}g(y)\,dy=\int_0^\infty\frac{\partial}{\partial x}e^{-xy}g(y)\,dy=-\int_0^\infty ye^{-xy}g(y)\,dy$$
since $x>0$ you just need to assure yourself that $ye^{-y}g(y)$ tends to zero, which will be true for all functions that grow slower than exponential

Answer (score 2):

Let's take the derivative under the integral:

$$f'(x) = -\int_{0}^{\infty} y e^{-xy} g(y) \, dy.$$

We need to show that this is absolutely integrable. Note that $|y e^{-xy} g(y)| \leq y |g(y)|$. Since $g \in L^1(0, \infty)$, it follows that $\int_{0}^{\infty} y |g(y)| \, dy < \infty$ (this is because $y e^{-xy}$ is bounded by 1 for $y \geq 0$ and $x > 0$).

Answer (score 1):

**Theorem**: Let $(\Omega, d\omega)$ be a measure space, $X$ an open set of $\mathbb R$, and $\phi: X \times \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ satisfies the following conditions:

- For each $x \in X$, $\omega \mapsto \phi(x,\omega)$ is integrable.
- For each $\omega \in \Omega$, the derivative $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,\omega)$ of $x \mapsto \phi(x,\omega)$ exists.
- There is an integrable function $\Theta:\Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ such that $|\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,\omega)| \leq |\Theta(\omega)|$ for all $x \in X$ and $\omega \in \Omega$.

Then the function

$$f(x) = \int\limits_{\Omega} \phi(x,\omega)d\omega$$

is differentiable, with $f'(x) = \int\limits_{\Omega} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} \phi(x,\omega)d\omega.$

Proof: Let $p(x) = \int\limits_{\Omega} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x} h(x,\omega)d\omega$.  We want to show that for each $x \in X$,

$$\lim\limits_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h} = p(x).$$

To do this, it suffices to show that for each sequence of real numbers $h_n \in X$ converging to $0$,

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x+h_n) - f(x)}{h_n} = p(x).$$

Let $$\psi_n(\omega) = \frac{\phi(x+h_n,\omega) - \phi(x,\omega)}{h_n}.$$

Of course for each $\omega \in \Omega$, $\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \psi_n(\omega) = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,\omega)$.  Also, by the mean value theorem, for each $n$ and $\omega$, there is a real number $a_n(\omega) \in X$ such that

$$\psi_n(\omega) = \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(a_n(\omega),\omega)$$
and therefore

$$|\psi_n(\omega)| = |\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(a_n(\omega),\omega)| \leq |\Theta(\omega)|.$$

Since the sequence of functions $\psi_n: \Omega \rightarrow \mathbb R$ converges to $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,\omega)$ pointwise, and there is an integrable function $\Theta$ for which $|\psi_n(\omega)| \leq |\Theta(\omega)|$, the dominated convergence theorem implies that $\omega \mapsto \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,\omega)$ is integrable, with

$$\lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \int\limits_{\Omega} \psi_n(\omega)d\omega = \int\limits_{\Omega} \frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,\omega) d\omega.$$

But

$$\lim\limits_n \int\limits_{\Omega} \psi_n(\omega)d\omega = \lim\limits_n \int\limits_{\Omega} \frac{\phi(x+h_n,\omega) - \phi(x,\omega)}{h_n} d \omega = \lim\limits_n \frac{\int\limits_{\Omega} \phi(x+h_n,\omega)d\omega - \int\limits_{\Omega} \phi(x,\omega)d\omega}{h_n}$$

$$ = \lim\limits_{n \to \infty} \frac{f(x+h_n) - f(x)}{h_n}.$$
$\blacksquare$

For each $c > 0$, you can apply the theorem with $\Omega = (0,\infty)$ and $X = (c,\infty)$, taking $\phi(x,y) = e^{-xy}g(y)$, so that $\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,y) = -y e^{-xy}g(y)$.  If you take $\Theta(y) = c^{-1}e^{-1}g(y)$, then $|\frac{\partial \phi}{\partial x}(x,y)| \leq |\Theta(y)|$ for all $x \in X$ and $y \in \Omega$.  The theorem implies that

$$f(x) = \int_0^{\infty} e^{-xy}g(y)dy$$

is differentiable for all $x \in (c,\infty)$, with derivative

$$f'(x) = \int_0^{\infty} -ye^{-xy}g(y)dy.$$

Since $f$ is differentiable on $(c,\infty)$ for every $c > 0$ with the given derivative, it is also differentiable on the union of all such intervals, that is $(0,\infty)$, with the same derivative.  This completes the proof.

Comment: I would need a direct proof for this. It actually states in the problem "only use results we know." I assume that is stated because this theorem exists, but we didn't cover it. Is there any way you could work on a direct proof?

Comment: Aren't you supposed to do it though?  lol

Comment: Why do you think I'm here? Because I'm struggling to do it. I don't see how to do it...

Comment: We're not here to do your homework for you.  If you demonstrate more of your own efforts/attempts to solve it, people will help you more.

Comment: You might check out a reputable real analysis textbook that has "differentiation under the integral sign"-like theorems, read the proof, and see if you can adapt the proof for your problem.

Comment: I am unsure of how to start, so I really cannot provide any work. If you are unwilling to help me I'd rather you just move on with your day. It is not helpful, in fact very discouraging, when people refuse to help simply because I do not have an attempt. I literally don't know what to do!

Comment: If you're unable to make any attempt whatsoever then you should go back to previous material and get the basics of measure theory/real analysis down.  Getting answers for questions that you are completely unprepared for is a horrible way to learn mathematics.

Comment: Anyway, I have edited my answer and given a complete proof of the Theorem I mentioned.  As far as I can tell, it can be applied to answer your question when the integrals over $\int_0^{\infty}$ are replaced by $\int_c^{\infty}$, where $c$ is an arbitrarily small positive real number.  I'm afraid I don't immediately know how to bridge the gap to take $c$ all the way to $0$, but you might consult some standard references for how people do such things e.g. with the differentiability of the gamma function.

Comment: Oh I think I can do that! I've done similar things where I've had to extend the limit to 0. I should be able to work on that now. I'll see if I can do it

Comment: Cool, good luck.  If you figure it out it'd be great to include your answer here so I can know it too

Comment: Actually the theorem I provided yields a complete proof, no further analysis necessary.  I have edited.